# Oculus Integration gives errors - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm getting the following errors after importing Oculus Integration from Unity Asset Store.
Using Unity 2019.4.40f1
[image]

Comment: uninstall the plugin, delete Library and Temp and obj folders, reinstall the plugin

Comment: @Jay Is it possible, the error is due to old Unity version? On 2021 LTS the Oculus integration didnt gave any error

Comment: Furqan Ahmen I think you're correct. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-82022#description
This source says *"Minimal Unity Version - The minimum supported Unity version for Oculus app development is 2021.3 LTS."*. It is bizzare to me that the asset store let you install it on an incompatibhle version but  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2019.4.40f1 is not supported by Oculus integration
[image]